# PersistentFSM doesn't persist to journal

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-persistence

I'm trying to test a new feature of Akka 2.4 - `PersistentFSM` (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/persistence.html#Persistent_FSM) with the simple example below.

This example generates 5 random integers and ads it to the sequence. What I'd like it to do is to persist the data and on the next run of the application keep appending to existing sequence of numbers. Current documentation on `PersistentFSM` is a little scarce and there's no clear way how to make this work. Any ideas?

TestFSM.scala:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.persistence.fsm.PersistentFSM
import akka.persistence.fsm.PersistentFSM.FSMState
import scala.reflect._
import scala.util.Random

final case class SetNumber(num: Integer)

sealed trait State extends FSMState
case object Idle extends State {
    override def identifier: String = "Idle"
}
case object Active extends State {
    override def identifier: String = "Active"
}

sealed trait Data {
    def add(number: Integer): Data
}
case object Empty extends Data {
    def add(number: Integer) = Numbers(Vector(number))
}
final case class Numbers(queue: Seq[Integer]) extends Data {
    def add(number: Integer) = Numbers(queue :+ number)
}

sealed trait DomainEvt
case class SetNumberEvt(num: Integer) extends DomainEvt

class Generator extends Actor with PersistentFSM[State, Data, DomainEvt] {

    override def applyEvent(domainEvent: DomainEvt, currentData: Data): Data = {
        domainEvent match {
            case SetNumberEvt(num) => currentData.add(num)
        }
    }

    override def persistenceId: String = "generator"

    override def domainEventClassTag: ClassTag[DomainEvt] = classTag[DomainEvt]

    startWith(Idle, Empty)

    when(Idle) {
        case Event(SetNumber(num), Empty) =>
            goto(Active) applying SetNumberEvt(num)
    }

    when(Active) {
        case Event(SetNumber(num), numbers: Data) =>
            println(numbers)
            stay applying SetNumberEvt(num)
    }

    initialize()

}

object TestFSM extends App {

    val system = ActorSystem()

    val actor = system.actorOf(Props[Generator])

    actor ! SetNumber(Random.nextInt())
    actor ! SetNumber(Random.nextInt())
    actor ! SetNumber(Random.nextInt())
    actor ! SetNumber(Random.nextInt())
    actor ! SetNumber(Random.nextInt())

    Thread.sleep(1000)
    system.terminate()

}
```

reference.conf:

```
akka.persistence.journal.plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.inmem"
akka.persistence.snapshot-store.plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local"
akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.dir = "target/journal"
akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local.dir = "target/snapshots"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what test you are doing to establish whether or not the events are getting persisted?

Comment: @mattinbits at the moment I'm not even sure how to make it work. This seems to be a merged functionality of `FSM` and `PersistentActor` without a complete example. From documentation: "PersistentFSM handles the incoming messages in an FSM like fashion. Its internal state is persisted as a sequence of changes, later referred to as domain events." - this suggests a different approach from the usual `persist` method which is now even deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PersistentFSM` now implicitly persists both the state changes and the domain events as the FSM proceeds.

Although the documentation you link to is lacking, it is possible to see from the code that `persistAll` is getting called under the hood at the appropriate point: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.4.0/akka-persistence/src/main/scala/akka/persistence/fsm/PersistentFSM.scala#L110

Suggest you test the implementation as you have it to see whether it does indeed persist.

EDIT:

I was able to execute your code, unchanged, and see the `target/journal` directory get created. I used the following `build.sbt`:

```
name := "Scratch"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

sbtVersion := "0.13.7"

mainClass := Some("TestFSM")

fork := true

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence" % "2.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.iq80.leveldb"            % "leveldb"          % "0.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.fusesource.leveldbjni"   % "leveldbjni-all"   % "1.8"
```

And the following `application.conf`:

```
akka.persistence.journal.plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb"
akka.persistence.snapshot-store.plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local"
akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.dir = "target/journal"
akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local.dir = "target/snapshots"
```

I think `application.conf` is the appropriate way to specify application specific conf rather than `reference.conf`, which is meant for libraries.

Comment: If `persistAll` is called under the hood then this would be working, would it not? The folder `target/journal` is not even created which is what happens in a classic `PersistentActor` case using method `persist`.

Comment: You are using `akka.persistence.journal.inmem` which as the name suggests is an in memory only journal. This is why I asked above what you'd done to test if persistence was working. Try using `akka.persistence.journal.plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb"`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. I've changed it to `akka.persistence.journal.plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb"` now, but no difference - still no journal folder created.

Comment: See my edit above, when I execute your code, the directory is created.

Comment: Thanks, it must have been the application.conf that it wanted, everything works now.